# Customise the icons of the toolbar created using NavigationToolbar2Tk

Tags: python, toolbar, tkinter-canvas, matplotlib-widget

I want to customise the icons (like home, back, forward, pan etc) on the matplotlib toolbar. In this case I am writing a GUI with tkinter with embedded pyplot plot in the widget of the GUI and create the toolbar with `NavigationToolbar2Tk`.

After searching for a bit I didn't find a clear method to do it. My first approach was to define a child class that inherits everything from `NavigationToolbar2Tk` and than modify the method where the paths to the icons are located, placing the paths to my custom icons. I was trying to do something like this:

```
class custom_NavigationToolbar2Tk(NavigationToolbar2Tk):
    """Make a custom toolbar with custom icons"""

    def _set_image_for_button(self, button):
        """
        Ovveride this method to chose custom icons
        """
        path_regular = pathlib.Path(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "icons", os.path.basename(button._image_file)))
```

`_set_image_for_button` is the name of the method where the variable containing the icons paths `path_regular` is located. I want to only overide this variable from the parent class, while keeping everything else the same. When in my main code I call `custom_NavigationToolbar2Tk` it does create the toolbar but it seems to completely ignore the `_set_image_for_button` method in *my* code, so the icons remain the old one.

I found a workaround that works, that is I define only the `_set_image_for_button` method in my code with inside the entire code from `NavigationToolbar2Tk._set_image_for_button`, only replacing the original expression for the `path_regular` variable with my expression that gives the location of my custom icons and than I overide the original method like this:

```
NavigationToolbar2Tk._set_image_for_button = _set_image_for_button
```

And this does work as expected with old icons replaced by my new icons. But I dont like very much this solution and don't understand why the first approach doesn't work.

I found only 1 analogous question here [How do I configure a MatPlotLib Toolbar so that the buttons in the toolbars are ttk buttons instead of old Tk buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59606641/how-do-i-configure-a-matplotlib-toolbar-so-that-the-buttons-in-the-toolbars-are) but the solution doesn't work.